# How do I warn people about a scammer/swindler who has not yet been indicted wihout being defamatory?

Tags: defamation

I live in Australia. There is this person who cheats people all the time through devious schemes and convincing talks. I myself lost a few thousands of dollars from him. Two of my friends lost $50,000 and $30,000 respectively. He has yet to be indicted as I am in the process of suing him.

In the meanwhile, I am compelled to warn people about him as he is targeting people of my community and making us all look bad.

An article about him was published in top local news papers. I want to spread this article with a caption to warn people about him.

What is the best way to do so for it not to be defamatory and invite lawsuits?

This guy has been known to find legal loop holes and drag people to court.

Comment: The obvious, though possibly not legal, way would be anonymously.  [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) is your friend.

Comment: I intend to send in all messaging platforms such as SMS, Whatsapp, etc

Comment: Then a burner phone bought with cash may help.  If you have a method already decided perhaps add to question, but that will obviously limit your options.

Comment: if you are in the process of suing this person, your attorney should be giving you this advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For a start: don't use the words "scammer" or "swindler"

Stick to what you can 100% prove is true.

State facts: don't draw conclusions. This happened, then that happened, then I did this, then he did that etc.  Let the person you are communicating with draw their own conclusions.

### However, don't say anything!

You say "I am in the process of suing him". Therefore, everything about or connected with the case is [sub judice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub_judice). Anything you say could prejudice your case and may be contempt of court.

Comment: Thank you Dale, it's pretty clear now after searching around.

Comment: Couldn’t be formulate an opinion in a non-fact statement form that no reasonable person would consider a statement of fact as well? (It may still prejudice them for the lawsuit but should protect them from criminal charges or being made a counter claim or be sue for defamation, slander and/or libel, no?)

Comment: @kisspuska I can hold the opinion that you are a nice person (or not) - that’s not defamation because my opinion of your niceness is not a statement of fact. I can’t hold an opinion about you being a scammer - whether you are a scammer or not is an objective fact.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with Australian law, but in the US you can say anything as long as its true. So I would just say be able to back up everything you say.

But, I would just say what you're saying is confusing since "indictment" refers to a criminal case and "suing him" refers to civil.